# ‘IWorkbookWorksheetRangeRequestBuild’ does not contain a definition for ‘Format'

Tags: microsoft-graph-excel

I am using the Microsoft Graph SDK to update range format of the worksheet as code snippets shown below:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
var workbookRangeFormat = new WorkbookRangeFormat
{
    HorizontalAlignment = "Center",
    VerticalAlignment = "Top",
    RowHeight = 49
};
await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items[fileId].Workbook
    .Worksheets[sheetName].Range(range).Format
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(workbookRangeFormat);
```

But there is compiling error:

> error CS1061: 'IWorkbookWorksheetRangeRequestBuilder' does not contain
>   a definition for 'Format' and no accessible extension method 'Format'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'IWorkbookWorksheetRangeRequestBuilder' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Reference: [Update range format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/rangeformat-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp)

The Assembly Microsoft.Graph Version: 1.16.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the API, basically not yet complete even though the documentation says otherwise.  See here,[#233](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/233)